# Moving to OOP hopefully!

Tags: php

So I am trying to understand OOP more and use it.

The following code was written before i started using OOP.

```
//loop through all the users 
$game = "$_POST[Game]_teams";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM `users`") or die(mysql_error());
while( $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
    $u[] = $row['username'];
}
```

I have put the query into my database page like following:

```
   function selectAllUsers()
   {
        $q = "SELECT username FROM ".TBL_USERS."";
        mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
   }
```

I'm a little confused about how the rest could be different?
Would it be? Is it possible for anyone to help me without more code or understanding of my structure?

Comment: I am confused by the question, are you trying to transform your first example to OOP?

Comment: It's difficult to ascertain what is being asked exactly. Can you give us more details about what your trying to accomplish and where your confusions lie?

Comment: If you want to use OOP, PHP isn't really the language for it. PHP's is bolted on like that of Perl's.  "Technically" it's OOP, but semantically or stylistically, not even close.

Comment: Ahhh, yes i am trying to turn the first piece of code in OOP.

Comment: @Luke: OO is fundamentally orthogonal to an RDB.  We live in a world where most programmers do not understand that: basically they use a layer of ORM (Object/Relational Mapper) and then they *think* they do OO, but they really don't (and don't understand they really don't, and post clueless comments here disagreeing with me, because they don't realize they really, really, don't understand OO).  Enlightening read by Ted Neward: http://blogs.tedneward.com/2006/06/26/The+Vietnam+Of+Computer+Science.aspx

Comment: +1@Wizard! I'm often astonished by the amount of otherwise knowledgeable people that do not realize that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each function in your class should do *one* task and *one* task only and should be named appropriately.

Your `selectAllUsers` function should just select all users, as you have done so,

```
function selectAllUsers() {
 $q = "SELECT username FROM ".TBL_USERS."";
 return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
}
```

However, I added a `return` keyword, to return the *resource* which we can use later on.

You could then have a function called `generateUserArray`, which would populate an array of user's using the *returned* MySQL resource from the `selectAllUsers` function.

```
function generateUserArray() {
 $u = array();
 $result = $this->selectAllUsers();
 while( $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $u[] = $row['username'];
 }
 return $u;
}
```

With more information regarding your question, the more answers you will receive in regards to what your trying to accomplish, or clear up any confusion.

---

First, here is my test table (`users`) from my test database (`login`),

```
mysql> select * from users;
+-----------+-----------+
| Name      | Password  |
+-----------+-----------+
| aforloney | whatsup   |
| pam       | qwerty    |
+-----------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.15 sec)
```

And here is my test class in `MyClass.php`

```
class MyClass {

 function connect() {
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
  mysql_select_db("login");
 }

 function selectAllValues() {
  $q = "SELECT * FROM users";
  return mysql_query($q);
 }

 function printAllValues() {
  $result = $this->selectAllValues();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo $row['Name'] . " and " . $row['Password'] . "<br/>";
  }
 }
}
```

Which you could then invoke from a `Main` class like so,

```
class Main {    

// other variables...

// __construct is an object's constructor, it's what gets called when 
// you create a new Main object

  function __construct() {

   $myClass = new MyClass();
   $myClass->connect();
   $myClass->selectAllValues();
   $myClass->printAllValues(); 

  }
}
```

And then called,

```
$m = new Main(); // will invoke the __construct function
```

Which will output to the browser,

```
 aforloney and whatsup
 pam and qwerty
```

---

As a side note, just to avoid any other confusion, my `MyClass` and `Main` example were two classes inside the *same* PHP file. If you were to use the above code examples and try to create a `MyClass` object, it would throw an error.

If you had wanted to instantiate an object that is defined in *another* class, you would need an [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement.

So with two different PHP files, I would change my code for the `Main` class like so,

```
<?php
include ('MyClass.php'); 
class Main {
 ...
}
?>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what the OP had wanted, but I decided to post my answer anyways. If the answer is not what the OP had intended, I will remove the post.

Comment: I think this is helpful. How would i access this function on my other page?
$database->generateUserArray() ???
Would that list all the users for me?

Comment: I tried to mimic to the best of my abilities your example, but I am sure you can edit to your own needs.

Comment: I am over the moon with that answer. That has really put me where I need to be. Completely understand the existing code I had now. Thankyou very much

Comment: Not a problem, happy OOP'ing :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should consider switching to PDO (see php.net). It has by nature a more OOP-ish approach and provides a better and more intuitive API plus lots of other features contrary to the mysql_* functions.

Extremely simple example: Here we are fetching user data from the database and populate User-objects with that data.

```
<?php
class UserMapper {
    protected $connection;
    public function __construct(PDO $connection) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function findAll() {
       $statement = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
       $statement->execute();
       return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');
    }
}

class User {
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $password;
}

$connection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=users;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root');
$userMapper = new UserMapper($connection);

$users = $userMapper->findAll();
print_r($users);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've in the past used some php metaprogramming to accomplish this.
http://iain.codejoust.com/2010/02/very-basic-php-orm/

The general idea is to create a model class, and setup a php __call handler enabling the database class intercepts the method called, sets up the arguments, then the Model class returns a SQL string created from the arguments and the function in the Model.

When the function is called, the result is a PDO object with the results of the SQL query contained within.

You also can take a look at PHP ORMs such as http://www.doctrine-project.org/ to provide a very OOP enabled interface with less effort.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I would say your example shifts from structural to functional but I would not say makes an example of object oriented.

an object oriented example would be more like:

```
class user {

public $username;
public $password;

public function showUsername(){
  echo 'Username is '.$this->username;
}

public function showPassword(){
  echo 'Password is '.$this->password;
}
}
```

Comment: Wow, alot of nerd rage it seems on this site. I thought the idea was to downvote misinformation, not difference of opinion.